# Web Design fluidity

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm looking for someone to steer me in the right direction.  I have a functional web page that runs crisply on my 13" MacBook. The issue is viewing the web page at different sizes and how the elements get distorted.  What kind of things need to be done to ensure it looks crisp and beautiful on any screen size. Does it require me to use percentages when detailing height and widths of elements or does it require some javascript.

I realize this is broad and all im looking for is someone to steer me towards what should be changed so I can get the site live.

Thanks!

Comment: read up on responsive design and adaptive design

Answer (score 1):

General direction:

You want to check out [media queries](http://mediaqueri.es/) to make your design [responsive](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries) to different viewing media. You will want to consider other meta tags such as ones defining the viewport size, but in general you can do it all with CSS.

Here are example queries that can wrap your custom CSS rules for each device size:

```
    /* Smaller than standard 960 (devices and browsers) */
    @media only screen and (max-width: 959px) {}

    /* Tablet Portrait size to standard 960 (devices and browsers) */
    @media only screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 959px) {}

    /* All Mobile Sizes (devices and browser) */
    @media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {}

    /* Mobile Landscape Size to Tablet Portrait (devices and browsers) */
    @media only screen and (min-width: 480px) and (max-width: 767px) {}

    /* Mobile Portrait Size to Mobile Landscape Size (devices and browsers) */
    @media only screen and (max-width: 479px) {}
```

Obviously you will want to fill-in the CSS rules as needed to ensure your content doesn't get scrunched.

A good strategy is to design for small mobile application, then go bigger from there. That way you don't find yourself trying to cram way. too. much. into a small interface.

In general you can also use the `float:left;` property for your main layout blocks (instead of absolute positioning, etc) That way your sidebar, etc will float above/below your main content when the parent element is too narrow to have both side-by-side.

Also, yes. You can use percentages, etc to fill areas fluidly. Use `background-` properties instead of `<img>` tags. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you may take bootstrap as a refer!

It is responsive, and will display almost the same on different resolution screen!

So try something like this.

and if you want to make your site looks like the same on all screen, try precentage!(but not suggested!)

Answer (score 0):

You will need [**css3-mediaqueries**](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/) for responsive designs or fluid designs

We Can assign different `stylesheets` depending on `browser window size`.

You must know How to use [**CSS Media Queries & Using Available Space**](http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/)

Have a go here 
[**What are CSS Media Queries
and how to implement them.**](http://cssmediaqueries.com/what-are-css-media-queries.html)
 too

I thought of not editing my answer any more, but i have got some good points to change my mind From http://www.webmonkey.com/2011/06/tips-tricks-and-best-practices-for-responsive-design/

> 1. Use @media to scale your layout for any screen, but remember that
>      this alone isn’t really responsive design.
> 2. Use liquid layouts that can accommodate any screen size. Don’t
>      simply design one look for the iPhone/Android, one for tablets and
>      one for the desktop. Keep it liquid, otherwise what happens when
>      some new, intermediate screen size suddenly becomes popular?
> 3. Roll your own grids based on the specifics of your site’s content.
>      Canned grid systems will rarely fit the bill. The problem with
>      canned grids is that they don’t fit your unique content. Create
>      layouts from the content out, rather than the canvas (or grid) in.
> 4. Start small. Start with the smallest size screen and work your way
>      up, adding @media rules to float elements into the larger windows of
>      tablet and desktop browsers. Start with a narrow, single-column
>      layout to handle mobile browsers and then scale up from there rather
>      than the other way around.
> 5. Use the Respond or CSS3 Media Queries JavaScript libraries to
>      bootstrap @media query support into older browsers that won’t
>      otherwise know what to do with it. Starting with the smallest screen
>      and working your way up means it’s the desktop browsers that need to
>      handle @media, make sure older browsers work by using polyfills like
>      Respond.
> 6. Forget Photoshop, build your comps in the browser. It’s virtually
>      impossible to mock up liquid layouts in Photoshop, start in the
>      browser instead.
> 7. Scale images using img { max-width: 100%; }. For very large images,
>      consider using something like Responsive Images to offer the very
>      smallest screens smaller image downloads and then use JavaScript to
>      swap in larger images for larger screen.
> 8. Embrace lazy loading. There may be items on your site, auxiliary
>      content that’s nice to have, but not essential. Load that content
>      using JavaScript after the primary content is done loading.
> 9. Forget about perfect. Even with these suggestions you’re still
>      leaving out users who have old browsers with JavaScript disabled.
>      Such users are increasingly rare and if they see the mobile layout
>      on their desktop, guess what, it’s not the end of the world. Your
>      site is still perfectly usable.